# Filepath contains invalid characters

Tags: c#, file-io, filepath, notsupportedexception

I've created a small program that creates compressed backups. Please see the edit below.

*The filepaths have a colon in them that is generating a `NotSupportedException` when I try to run it.

If I have the following path:

`C:\Testing facility\SampleDirectory`

What can I replace `:` with in order that my program will process the filepath, but still find the correct directory/file?*

The example shown in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280(v=vs.110).aspx) says nothing about any issues with colons or any other illegal characters, am I doing something wrong?

My directory compression code is as follows:

```
private void CompressDirectory()
{
    zipPath = backupPath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':', '-') + ").";

    try
    {
        ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(sourcePath, zipPath, CompressionLevel.Optimal, true);
        getresultmessage();
    }
    catch (IOException v)
    {
        errMsg = "Failed trying to start compression. \n" + v.ToString();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
After some more debugging, I've realised that the filestrings are being double-appended for soem reason. By this, I mean that `sourcePath` has gained the value:
`"C:\\Testing facility\\SampleDirectory"`
ans a similar event has occurred with the backup path.

Why is this, and what can I do to fix it?

Comment: To fix it you need to share your code for creating the sourcePath and backupPath.

Answer (score 1):

try this it might work just fine for you

**@"C:\Testing facility\SampleDirectory"**

Comment: I can't do this, because the file paths are populated with strings from a textbox.

Comment: doest that textbox contains something else than the file path and are there multiple paths or single path?

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

`DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace(':', '-')`

with:

`DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm")`

Remove `")."`

As for your **Edit** - You see `\\` because `\` is [escaped](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx).

Comment: +1 for this as it also allows easy sorting of files in the directory by date